# javascript clique em option

Tags: javascript

preciso simular um click em uma option

Quando eu clico no botão, ele altera o valor do option, mas o option nao chama o evento onchange, o onchange só chama quando eu faço a seleção como mouse

segue o codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <select id="mySelect" name ="mySelect" onChange="jsfunction()">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option>Pineapple</option>
            <option>Banana</option>
        </select>

        <p>Click the button to deselect options.</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {

                var tm = 'Pineapple'
                var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
                for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++)
                {
                    var v = select.children[i].text;
                    var cp = tm.localeCompare(v);
                    if (cp == 0)
                    {
                         select.children[i].selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            function jsfunction() {
                alert("hi");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apesar de estar bem confusa sua pergunta, não é só chamar a função jsfunction() dentro de myFunction()?

Comment: Vamos por partes: 1º explicar melhor a tua pergunta, 2º indentação de código ja ouviu falar? se nós que estamos a tentar ajudar mal percebemos o código assim como vais tu perceber quando tens essas duvidas todas? Uma coisa é certa, esta e outras perguntas que eu vi aqui hoje eram logo fechadas no site principal do stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Cara fiz um pequeno exemplo para ti, talvez te de uma ajuda, é um pouco diferente do teu codico mas pode te dar um guia:

```
<style>
 #modelo{
  background:red;
 }
</style>


<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()"> 
<option value="Audi">Audi 
<option value="BMW">BMW 
<option value="Mercedes">Mercedes 
<option value="Volvo">Volvo 
</select> 
<br><br> 
<div id="modelo" style="display:none;">Escolha um modelo
 <br>
 <select> 
 <option value="x1">x1</option> 
 <option value="x2">x2</option> 
 <option value="x3">x3</option> 
 <option value="x4">x4</option> 
 </select>
</div> 


<script> function myFunction() { 
var select = 
document.getElementById('mySelect'); 
select.addEventListener('change', 
function(){ 
document.getElementById("
modelo").style.display="block"
}
)};
</script>
```

Pode usar o document.addEventListener com o "parâmetro" **change** e carregar a função no onload em sua página e usar o mesma lógica para detectar a mudança em um selecta.